# Using Case statement in sqlite, trouble getting the results I'm looking for

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, sum, case

I am having difficulty with a SQL query. I'm using sqlite.

I have a table `expenses`. I'm trying to use a `CASE`statement to select and sum values. Here's some sample data:

[image]

This is the query which is not getting what I'd like...

```
SELECT e.category, 
  CASE 
    WHEN e.schedule ='None' AND e.created_at > '2014-02-01 00:00:00 +0000' THEN SUM(e.amount) 
    WHEN e.schedule = 'Daily' THEN SUM(e.amount)*28.000000 
    WHEN e.schedule = 'Mon - Fri' THEN SUM(e.amount)*20 
    WHEN e.schedule = 'Weekly' THEN SUM(e.amount)*4.000000 
    WHEN e.schedule = 'Every 4 Weeks' THEN SUM(e.amount)*1.083333333333 
    WHEN e.schedule = 'Monthly' THEN SUM(e.amount)*1 
  ELSE 0 
  END 
AS totalValue FROM expenses e GROUP BY e.category ORDER BY e.category
```

Below is a pic of what the query returns.

What I would like to see in total value for `Housing` 420, this is because there is are three records with the `category` "Housing", one of which has a `schedule` of "None" (record id 2) and was created in January. The other two (records 10 and 16) have a `schedule` of Monthly. In my `CASE` I try to only select the schedules with a `created_at` greater than the 1st of Feb:

```
    WHEN e.schedule ='None' AND e.created_at > '2014-02-01 00:00:00 +0000' THEN SUM(e.amount)
```

Or with a schedule value other than "None", in this case:

```
    WHEN e.schedule = 'Monthly' THEN SUM(e.amount)
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a result of 495 (300 + 120 + 75). It's summing all the records with a particular `category` if it finds a record that fits the case statement!

[image: Sample Output]

Please can you help me rewrite the case so that I get the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem with the query is that you are using `e.schedule` in the `select` list but it is not in a `group by`.  This is usually the sign of a problem.

I think you want to move the entire `case` statement inside the `sum()`:

```
SELECT e.category, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN e.schedule ='None' AND e.created_at > '2014-02-01 00:00:00 +0000' THEN e.amount
                WHEN e.schedule = 'Daily' THEN e.amount*28.000000 
                WHEN e.schedule = 'Mon - Fri' THEN e.amount*20 
                WHEN e.schedule = 'Weekly' THEN e.amount*4.000000 
                WHEN e.schedule = 'Every 4 Weeks' THEN e.amount*1.083333333333 
                WHEN e.schedule = 'Monthly' THEN e.amount*1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) as totalValue
FROM expenses e
GROUP BY e.category
ORDER BY e.category;
```

Otherwise, you might want to move `e.schedule` to the `group by` clause to have a separate row for each schedule within each category.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check and see if this has the desired results. Thanks. As it happens, however, I do actually have the e.category in the group by, see the last line in the query above: 'AS totalValue FROM expenses e GROUP BY e.category ORDER BY e.category'

Comment: Thank you this seems to work! What a relief, thanks.